# #identityserver 500 error When using Authorize Attribute

Tags: identityserver4

I am unable to call any method marked with either attribute:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
[Authorize]
```

I have setup the IdentityServer project and am able to to get access token from the project.

The web api project has the following configuration setup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            
             
                services.AddControllers();
                var idserver = "https://ipaddressofidntityserver";
                services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                    .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
                    {
                        options.Authority = idserver;

                        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                        {
                            ValidateAudience = false
                        };
                    });
        }
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication(); 

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

Any thoughts or help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you include some stack-trace? or log-details?

Comment: What does your "https://ipaddressofidntityserver" look like? just IP-address or domain name or localhost? HTTPS does not work with just an IP-Address to your IdentityServer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have not set the default route or used Route attribute in the web api controller.

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

or provide Route attribute over the default get method.

```
[Route("/")]
```